# Testing Plugins for Multisite

Tags: plugin-development, multisite, testing

I have recently published a WordPress plugin and it works great on single sites. I was informed that the plugin is not working correctly on multi-site installations and I understand a few of the reasons why. I have updated the code and need a way to now test my updated code before going to a live customer's multi-site installation.

I have a single site installation of WordPress setup for testing purposes but need to test on a multi-site installation.

From what I can find the only way to do this would be to setup an entire multi-site installation with at least two sites on the network to test my plugin.

Is setting up an entire multi-site installation of WordPress the only/preferred way for plugin developers, or is there a quicker testing environment available.

Comment: Setting up a local multisite install shouldn't be that much more difficult than a single site, and a lot of times plugins that work on multisites work just fine on a single site

Comment: @TomJNowell my current single site testing environment is on a subdomain. I will take your suggestion and just go ahead and go create a multi-site testing environment on a local server laying around my house. and use my hosts file to save the cost of a domain since it will be for local testing only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used several popular plugins on my multisite without problems.

The only issue I had was when I found that a plugin wasn't working on a sub-site like I thought it should. Turns out that was my fault - the plugin wasn't activated/enabled on that sub-site. Doh!

But it all depends on how the plugin is written, and how it is expected to work on a site. Most plugins, as Tom J Nowell stated/implied, should work just fine on multisite and sub-sites.

Comment: Yes, that is the main problem I am facing. My plugin creates database tables which I was doing with ->prefex and am now doing instead with ->base_prefix since I need to share the tables between the network and if I duplicated the tables on each site then all of the data would be duplicate... I was just looking for a way to test without creating a local multisite installation. I was looking for a possible testing environment that resets itself or something similar to download.

Comment: Rather than a separate table for each prefix, why not one table with a field for the prefix. Then filter out only those records that match the prefix. Results in only one additional table no matter how many subsites you have.

Comment: I accepted your answer since it was the only answer. That is how I developed the plugin with all sites sharing the same tables, the problem I ran into is when I made my queries using prefix instead of base_prefix and the subsites were not accessing the data.